# Выделить слово в RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Как двойным кликом по слову в `RichTextBox` выделить его и отобразить над ним `Panel` (панель изначально скрыта и должна появляться когда происходит клик по слову)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно повесить на `RichTextBox` событие `SelectionChanged()`, которое происходит после изменения выбора (выделения) текста в `RichTextBox`:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Проверяем что длина выбранного текста больше нуля,
    // иначе panel1 станет видимой при вводе текста
    if (richTextBox1.SelectedText.Length > 0)
       panel1.Visible = true;
    else
       panel1.Visible = false;
}
```

Двойным кликом изменится выделение слова и как раз сработает событие `richTextBox1_SelectionChanged`

**Update**

Для установления позиции события нужно использовать `MouseEventArgs`. В моем методе `EventHandler` не сможет принять `MouseEventArgs`. Тогда нужно взять за основу метод @AlexanderPetrov. Единственно,

```
panel.Location = e.Location;
```

позиция `panel` будет считаться с левого верхнего угла формы, так как событие происходит в `richTextBox`, и за начало координат берется верхний левый угол именно `richTextBox`. То есть Вам нужно еще посчитать координаты Вашей `panel`:

Координата `X` будет равна:

```
e.Location.X + richTextBox1.Location.X - panel1.Width / 2
```

`richTextBox1.Location.X` - координата `X` левого верхнего угла `richTextBox1`;

`e.Location.X` - координата `X` в самом `richTextBox1`.

Из этой суммы вычитаем `panel1.Width / 2`, чтобы левый край `panel` не был над началом слова, а был смещен, т.о. что `panel` будет надвисать над словом.

Координата `Y` будет равна:

```
e.Location.Y + richTextBox1.Location.Y - panel1.Height - richTextBox1.Height
```

`e.Location.Y + richTextBox1.Location.Y` - то же самое, что в `X`.
Из этой суммы вычитаем высоту `panel1.Height` и `richTextBox1.Height`, чтобы `panel1` не перекрывала `richTextBox1`.
Итого:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{            
    int length = richTextBox1.SelectionLength;
    // проверяем длину выбранного текста, если что-то выбрано, 
    // то показываем panel1
    if (length > 0)
    {
        int startIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        string word = richTextBox1.Text.Substring(startIndex, length).TrimEnd();
        int X = e.Location.X + richTextBox1.Location.X - panel1.Width / 2;
        int Y = e.Location.Y + richTextBox1.Location.Y - panel1.Height - richTextBox1.Height;
        panel1.Location = new Point(X, Y);
        panel1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Также оставляем событие:

```
private void richTextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Если нет выбранного текста,
    // скрываем panel1
    if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
        panel1.Visible = false;             
}
```

Comment: А если выделение с текста снять, то как в таком случае скрыть панель? И как отображать эту панель над выделенным словом?

Comment: @Aino, обновил ответ. Если условие не выполняется, то скрываете `panel`.

Comment: Все работает. Еще вопрос. Можно сделать так, что бы эта панель появлялась над выделенным словом? Если выделю другое слово, то панель появится над ним.

Comment: @Aino - скомбинируйте два события: показывать/скрывать панель в событии `SelectionChanged`, координаты задавать в событии `MouseDoubleClick`.

Comment: @Aino, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Sv__t Панель не появляется, даже в новом проекте.

Comment: @Aino, все работает. Ссылка на проект https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7zklISEuXGIWFFYVUZpQWY3dHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sv__t кажется я понял в чем проблема. RichTextBox у меня почти на всю форму и текст из множества строк и нужно чтобы эта панель появлялась именно на RichTextBox и именно над словом. В Вашем методе панель появляется слишком отдаленно и в случае изменения размера формы панель появляется непонятно где.

Comment: @Aino, тогда измените `int Y = e.Location.Y + richTextBox1.Location.Y -  panel1.Height - 10`      
 ( `-10` чтобы `panel` не закрывала текст).

Answer (score 2):

Слово автоматически выделяется двойным кликом, так что ничего дополнительно делать не нужно.

Показать панель в нужном месте элементарно: координаты клика есть, просто устанавливаем их и вызываем `Show`.

Дополнительно я написал, как получить выделенное слово.

```
private void RichTextBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int startIndex = richTextBox.SelectionStart;
    int length = richTextBox.SelectionLength;
    string word = richTextBox.Text.Substring(startIndex, length).TrimEnd();

    panel.Location = e.Location;
    panel.Show();
}
```